# Laravel Paypal Remove Package but Error is still there

Tags: laravel, paypal

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
        "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

config/app.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Application Environment
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
      | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
      | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
      |
     */

      'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Application Debug Mode
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
      | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
      | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
      |
     */
      'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Application URL
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
      | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
      | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
      |
     */
      'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Application Timezone
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
      | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
      | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
      |
     */
      'timezone' => 'UTC',
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Application Locale Configuration
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
      | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
      | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
      |
     */
      'locale' => 'en',
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Application Fallback Locale
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
      | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
      | the language folders that are provided through your application.
      |
     */
      'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    /*  
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Encryption Key
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
      | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
      | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
      |
     */
      'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
      'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Logging Configuration
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
      | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
      | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
      |
      | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
      |
     */
      'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Autoloaded Service Providers
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
      | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
      | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
      |
     */
      'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,

        ],
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Class Aliases
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
      | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
      | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
      |
     */
      'aliases' => [
      'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
      'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
      'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
      'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
      'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
      'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
      'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
      'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
      'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class, 
      'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
      'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
      'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
      'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
      'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
      'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
      'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
      'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
      'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
      'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
      'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
      'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
      'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
      'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
      'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
      'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
      'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
      'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
      'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
      'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
      'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
      'Flash' => Laracasts\Flash\Flash::class,
      ],
      ];
```

I already removed the Paypal providers and alias and updated the json file but still error is still there 'Netshell/Paypal/PaypalServiceProvider' Not found.
Need help with this. thanks

Comment: check if you have a controller, model or any file which include `Netshell/Paypal/PaypalServiceProvider`

Comment: Yes man, I already deleted it. But error still persists.

Comment: try search `PaypalServiceProvider` inside your folder using your text editor sublime for example

Comment: I'm using netbeans but I have pre installed sublime. What is the shortcut for that in sublime?

Comment: ctrl + shift + f just paste that text in `find:` and folder location in `where:`

Comment: It says no find pattern. I already deleted the PaypalController and json line where i required it. Since i don't already need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132053/discussion-between-a-sand-and-beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that you are trying to include `PaypalServiceProvider` some where in your laravel file

To fix that find `PaypalServiceProvider` in your laravel project using your text editor sublime for example and delete it

Just follow as this

https://gyazo.com/fbe54e7197db5a627433c6efe2fa0e94

Answer (score 0):

you can easily run the command :

```
**composer require  package_name**
```

in this case if you want to remove paypal package  so exucut :

```
**composer require  srmklive/paypal**
```